# Just a drop in the/an ocean ?

Tags: meaning

I wonder why people use "in the ocean" while grammatically it is incorrect to use. Shouldn't it be "in an ocean" ?

and also I got a doubt while typing the above sentence.  Should I have been typed "when grammatically" instead of "while grammatically"

Thanks!

Comment: It could have been 'in an ocean'; but that's not the idiom. I suspect that whoever coined the term was only familiar with one. In any case it's perfectly grammatical either way.

Comment: There is a difference between grammar and semantics. There is nothing -- absolutely nothing -- *grammatically* wrong with the famous sentence "colorless green ideas sleep furiously". Semantically, it's nonsense. As to whether there's something *semantically* wrong with "an ocean" when there exist multiple oceans -- nah, just like I can say "I'm going to *the* store", I can and do say "I'm going to visit *the* ocean this weekend", trusting that *you* know which store, and which ocean.

Comment: Immediately following ' ... grammatically it is incorrect to use.' by  'Shouldn't it be "in an ocean" ?' seems to indicate a sudden onset of doubt. 'The' is often used in ways some grammars don't mention. 'We're going to the cinema tomorrow' doesn't specify a particular cinema. 'We like holidays by the sea' doesn't hint at which sea. Both are idiomatic, and cannot be labelled ungrammatical.

Comment: Keep in mind that all the oceans of Earth connect with each other, so a drop of water in one raises the level (infinitesimally) in all of them.  Using "the" simply acknowledges this fact.

Comment: Since you are new here, I'll point you to [ell.se], which may have been a better place to ask this question. [Read this meta post](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/3722) if you want more information.

Comment: Anyone who has an objection to this idiom should jump in the lake.

Answer (score 3):

Grammatically incorrect? What gives you that notion about *the ocean*?

It's not grammatically wrong (and I don't think this has anything to do with "connected oceans," either).

Using the definite article here doesn't imply there's only one ocean, and we need not have an aforementioned ocean to use a definite article.

We can use word "the" when we are making a **generic reference to something** (see Definition 7 at [Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/the)). For example:

- The lion is king of the jungle
- Bob plays the clarinet
- It's just a drop in the bucket
- Out of the frying pan and into the fire
- That's money in the bank
- I wouldn't bet the mortgage on that
- I'm taking this to the post office

Answer (score 2):

Both "an" and "the" work here. While the sentiment of the phrase comes across with both, the turn of phrase I am familiar with uses "the" ocean. "The" sounds more ornamental and folksy too, implying a relationship with "the ocean" as if it is a character in both the writer's life and the reader's life.

Comment: 'An' is rarely used without a qualifying completer (... just a drop in an ocean of solitude). The idiom uses 'the ocean' (meaning the nebulous watery masses as a first step towards the metaphor), just like we say 'I'm off to the seaside' (without specifying exactly where).